# Allowing models to contain array of objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to have a model that contains an array of objects, without separating out those objects into having unique IDs?

For example, I have a slide with multiple parameters that may come back from the API:

```
slide: {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "stack-overflow-page",
    "type": "webpage"
    "parameters": [
        {"key": "url", "value": "http://stackoverflow.com"},
        {"key": "extension", "value": "/questions/ask"}
    ]
}
```

On my slide configuration page, I want to configure the slide and it's list of parameters. Since the parameters don't have explicit IDs (Composite ID - SlideID, Key), it would seem odd to separate these and make API calls for each parameter.

How can I configure and work with a model such as this?

Comment: `parameters` here is not a model; it's just an array-valued field of the `slide` model. Why would you think you would need to "separate them" (meaning what...?), and/or make separate API calls for them?

Comment: Can you define an array of values using DS.attr here? Do i need to define my own transform? My question is more of how to define the slide model properly.

Comment: The most straightforward approach is to simply do `parameters: DS.attr()`. You could define your own array transform it you really want to, but only if you need/want specialized behavior.

Comment: @torazaburo You're right, it's simpler than I expected it. I assumed if it wasn't one of the types defined in the docs, `string`, `number`, `boolean`, and `date`, the DS.attr() wouldn't resolve correctly. The only downside here is that isDirty doesn't work on the parameters, but that makes sense, and I can work around that. If you create an answer, I can mark you as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to simply do

```
parameters: DS.attr()
```

You could define your own array transform it you really want to, but only if you need/want specialized behavior. If you change something inside an element of the array, you will have to handle dirtification on your own, which you can do with

```
model
  .set('parameters.firstObject.key', 'www.google.com')
  .notifyPropertyChange('parameters');
```