# Attaching metadata to array in model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following model (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389963/allowing-models-to-contain-array-of-objects)):

```
slide: {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "stack-overflow-page",
    "type": "webpage",
    "parameters": [
        {"key": "url", "value": "http://stackoverflow.com"},
        {"key": "extension", "value": "/questions/ask"}
    ]
}
```

Each parameter has metadata, depending on the slide type:

```
widget: {
    "id": "webpage",
    "description": "Renders a webpage.",
    "parameters": [
         {"key": "url", "type": "string", "description": "The base URL to show."},
         {"key": "extension", "type": "string", "description": "The rest of the URL to attach, or any parameters."}
    ]
}
```

Currently, the "widget" metadata is loaded in the controller (note: ember-cli is used here):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    widget: function() {
        return this.store.find('widget', this.get('model.type'));
    }.property('model.type'),
});
```

However, when using the parameters in the template, I see no way to look up the metadata information for each parameter (for example, to show the parameter's description).

```
{{#each parameters}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">{{key}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{input type="text" value=value class="form-control"}}
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Additionally, if I attached the metadata to each parameter in the model, I assume it would be sent back to the server unnecessarily, since `parameters` is simply a `DS.attr()`. Is there a good way to look up the metadata information for each parameter?

Comment: Since I wasn't receiving any responses, I'm currently just sending the metadata along with the model, and ignoring it on PUT requests. This works, but I'm still curious if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [EmbeddedRecord Mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) is what you're looking for.  It was just abstracted out of the Active Model serializer and added to the generic REST serializer [in the most recent EmberData beta (Ember Data v1.0.0-beta.8)](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html), so you may need to upgrade to use it.  You'll still need to create a DS.Model for 'parameters' with two fields 'key' and 'value' for this to serialize correctly.

Comment: Using `DS.attr()` worked fine for retrieving and sending the model as-is listed above, so that bit works fine. I'm not sure how this would help in connecting in looking up the related "widget" parameter to match the "slide" parameter in order to display it's metadata in the `{{#each}}`.

Comment: If you run [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) I believe you'll find that Ember is serializing your `parameters` object as a string.  You need to define a model for `parameters` & use the EmbeddedRecord mixin for Ember to serialize it into an object.  Alternatively, you could write a custom serializer.

Comment: It's showing it as an Array as far as I can tell, with each parameter being an object having it's own `__ember_meta__` instance. Databinding works appropriately as well, although inspector doesn't show the object changes immediately (and isDirty doesn't track them on the slide object), model.save() works appropriately and the model/database both stay correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extractMeta hook from the JSON or REST Serializer -> https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L945 to parse your meta information.

If you want to access the metaData on your manyArray, you will need this patch -> https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/8544c29419d1ef909762a50beb434c219a34c846 
I completely forgot about it, I can merge it in a day or two so you don't have to edit ED yourself.